# If a sequence of measurable functions converges to $f_∗$ a.e. and to $g_∗$ in metric, then $f_* = g_*$ a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be the space of all measurable functions $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ from $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $(X,d)$ be a metric space with the metric $d:X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose that $\{f_j \in X\}_{j=1}^\infty$ be a sequence that converges to some function $f_*$ a.e. and at the same time converges to $g_* \in X$ in metric $d$, i.e., 
\begin{equation}
   \lim_{j \to \infty} d(f_j,g_*) = 0.
\end{equation}
Then, *can we conclude that both types of convergence have the a.e. same limit point, i.e., $f_* = g_*$ a.e.?*

---

I know that if $d$ is induced from $L^p$-norm ($1 \leq p< \infty$):
\begin{equation}
   d(f,g) := \Big ( \int_\Omega |f(x) - g(x)|^p \; d\mu(x) \Big )^{1/p},
\end{equation}
where $\mu$ is a measure on (a $\sigma$-algebra of) $\Omega$, then there is a subsequence $f_{j_n}$ that converges to $g_*$ a.e., and by the a.e. convergence $f_j \to f_*$, it is true that $f_* = g_*$ a.e.. Some related post for $p = 2$: [Can a sequence of functions converge to different functions pointwise and on average?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271202/can-a-sequence-of-functions-converge-to-different-functions-pointwise-and-on-ave?noredirect=1&lq=1)

In my post here, however, *I am seeking the general answer, where the metric $d$ is not a form of $L^p$-norm, but just arbitrarily given. Can you give a counter-example if it is not true? Or, can you give a specific required condition or form (perhaps on the metric $d$) for $f_* = g_*$ a.e. to be true?*

---

For your reference, this post is the general and refined version of the statement ([If a sequence of continuous functions converges to $f_*$ pointwisely and to $g_*$ in metric, then $f_* = g_*$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952582/if-a-sequence-of-continuous-functions-converges-to-f-pointwisely-and-to-g)) I previously posted, which turns out to be trivially NOT TRUE.

Comment: This isn't exactly your question, but it's closely related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87319/convergence-in-metric-and-a-e

Comment: @ user251257 I think $f_* = g_*$ a.e. is true with the trivial metric as long as it is defined with a.e. equal functions equivalenced. Obviously, by the convergence in $d$, there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(f_n, f_*) < 1/2$ for all $n \geq N$, implying $f_n = f_*$ a.e. for all $n \geq N$. This is obviously the a.e. convergence to $f_*$, and hence $f_* = g_*$ a.e.

Comment: @JaeYoungLee sorry. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true if you take an arbitrary metric. Let $\Omega = \{0\}$ with the counting measure. Hence, essentially we have $X = \mathbb{R}$.

Now, take any metric $d$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac1n \to 1$ w.r.t. the metric $d$.

Then, $f_j = 1/j$ converges towards $0$ a.e. on $\Omega = \{0\}$, but towards $1$ w.r.t. the metric $d$.

Comment: The shorter version of this answer: Since there is no connection assumed between the metric on $X$ on one hand, and the fact that $X$ consists of functions (which you could realize as the function $X\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, evaluating functions $f\in X$ at points $\omega\in\Omega$), there is no chance at all for the answer to be yes.